# Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

When I print the str the console, this is my output (copied and pasted):

```
'{ "1":"574fdd158e8f6581.jpg", "2":"b008442edfd5f9c5.jpg", "3":"14a88efa3eba4329.jpg", "4":"270ee8798e00032f.jpg", "5":"6b440c1ccc321e3a.jpg", "6":"272244601e225be9.jpg"}'
```

when I print out the typeof str it correctly identifies it as a string

from the documentation on Mozilla and w3schools they specify that the string should take the form:

`'{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'`

Yet when I try to do JSON.parse(str) I'm getting this error from the console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0

even the error being thrown seems to imply that the error is that the character at position 0 is the character that's supposed to be at position 0. I'm not quite sure why this isn't working properly.

I've tried removing the single space before the "1" and that still accomplishes nothing

Comment: Remove the single quotes `'` around the string (wherever they are coming from) when you put that into `JSON.parse`

Comment: I've tried this already and it gives an "unexpected end of json input" error

Comment: I can't reproduce this.

Comment: I don't know what you exactly have done, but your example without the single quotes is a perfectly valid json string. The error actually says `unexpected token '` so it's complaiing about the single quotes.

Comment: When I use stringify(str) I end up with "{ \"1\":\"574fdd158e8f6581.jpg\", \"2\":\"b008442edfd5f9c5.jpg\", \"3\":\"14a88efa3eba4329.jpg\", \"4\":\"270ee8798e00032f.jpg\", \"5\":\"6b440c1ccc321e3a.jpg\", \"6\":\"272244601e225be9.jpg }" and I'm assuming the issue is the last entry

Comment: Why would you stringify a string? The issue with json.parse is the single quotes, as the error clearly tells you.

Comment: I stringified the string as a method of trying to figure out what the issue is. Your solution was not a solution.

Comment: Yes it is the only solution. The character at position 0 is a single quote which is invalid at that position for json.parse and that's also what the error is telling you ...

Comment: It might be useful if you show us how you get that json and how you use it. Code is more useful.

Comment: Also, `'{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'` is an invalid JSON object because of the `'` that wrap it. That does, however, make it a valid json string when used like `var str = '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}';` but do note the single quotes: JSON.parse, when your json is correct, will ignore them because they're not a part of the data. The error you're getting indicates you're doing something wrong and code will help us see where. We know that your json is wrong because it has a single quote in it when it's passed to the parser.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, you are appending a *single-quote* which result in

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0

Example:

```js
const validJSON = `{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}`;
const invalidJSON = `'{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'`;
console.log({validJSON: JSON.parse(validJSON)});
console.log({invalidJSON: JSON.parse(invalidJSON)});
```

Open the console to view the error.